# Returning correct group label in footer

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

I want roll up the Amount Billed in the Details section by the first 5 characters in the Item column.  So `01-00.00` becomes `01-00`. I currently do this by grouping the Details by a Formula Field that grabs the left 5 characters the Item. So I wind up with a group footer that has the Item, Description, and the Amt Billed of 8000 (0 + 5000 + 0 + 3000).

But I cannot specify that I want the Description in my group footer to go with Item 01-00.00. Crystal chooses the Description for my group footer which goes with 01-00.03 because it's the last one in the list. How can I bring the correct description down?

Comment: Is there anything special about `Description I Want` that makes it the description you want? Or do you just always want the first description in the list to display in the footer?

Comment: There is something special about it.  So in my example, the description that I want is the word, "Mobilization".  The other descriptions are things like "Service" and "Start Up" which I don't want to pull.

Comment: That should be fine. My answer should still work so long as you can whip up a formula to determine which description is the special one.

Comment: What if I have multiple groupings.  My example just had one group of 01-00.00 thru 01-00.03 rolled up by "01-00", however, I'll end up with others like 01-01.00 thru 01-01.05.  I'll need to group the 01-00's together and the 01-01's together to get the numbers to roll up.  But I need to display something like:

Comment: 01-00       Description I need       $8000

Comment: 01-01 2nd Description I need $12000

Comment: That's where your formula comes into play. I don't know what specifically determines which description is special so you'll have to write that yourself. Is there any way you can tell which description you need based on something in the strings? Or in other fields?

Comment: Yes, so the description I need is the one that goes with the Item number that ends in ".00".  In other words, if the item is like 01-00.00, then I need the description that goes with it.  If it's like 01-00.01, it will also have a description, but not the one that I need.  I can write a formula to give me a value only when the item number ends in the ".00", but how will I relate that back to the group?  Let me work up a quick picture that probably says it better than I am in words.

Comment: Don't worry about the group. So long as you have a formula to detect the entry ending in ".00" you can use the shared variable without changing the group structure. I'll update my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: okay thank you for your help. I've updated my original question with a new picture to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No problem. I think I fully understand what you need now. My answer has been updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write suppressed formula to go in your Details section that looks something like:

```
Shared StringVar myDesc;
If Right({ItemNumber}, 2) = "00" Then
    myDesc := {Description}
```

Keep in mind `{ItemNumber}` refers to the field in your table *before* you crop off the decimals. Then make a second formula in your group footer:

```
Shared StringVar myDesc;
myDesc
```

Done correctly, the second variable will now display whichever Description had a corresponding ItemNumber that ended in `.00` originally. This shouldn't be affected by the order in which items are displayed in your group.

Comment: okay i'm going to give this a try.  may take a little bit. i'm still new to this.

Comment: Do the Formula Field name and the variable "myDesc" need to be named the same?

Comment: The actual names of the Formula Fields don't matter in this case. So long as they both use the same variable.

Comment: Hold up, if you haven't grouped them yet, the Shared Variables might not be necessary. Try grouping by "the first 5 characters in the Item column" and suppress the Details and Footer section. That will leave you with just the bottom part of your screenshot.

Comment: I'm getting the rolled up numbers fine.  But all blanks for description.  I'm grouped by the first 5 characters. I have the variable in place in the hidden details section and the other one in the footer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? You can blot out any sensitive information but it might help me to see it for myself.

Comment: Sure, can I post a screenshot to the thread, or does it have to be back on my original question?

Comment: You could do either. To post it into the comments you'll need to upload it to Imgur yourself first.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try replacing the `Global` keyword with `Shared` - Sometimes Crystal is a little picky about which is used.

Comment: Holy moly, I think that worked!!!  Not sure I totally understand why just yet, but it seems to have done the trick.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Will do.  Okay, I'll go ahead and ask...can you explain a bit more on why that works?

Comment: Sure! Your 01-01 Group prints 4 Details sections, so the formula actually runs 4 times. But you only set the Shared variable *1* time, because only 1 out of 4 records ends in '.00'

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A simple quick fix might be to just adjust the group order from ascending to descending. That way the last record is the top description. Right click group > Change Group

You can also change the group name using a formula under the options tab. Right click group > Change Group > Options > Customize Group Name Field > Use Formula

left({field.name},5)

Comment: Something like that might work, however, there will be other items in the list like 01-02.01, 01-02.02 that need to be sorted in ascending order.  If there is a way to only sort the items grouped by the 1st 5 chars in descending order but sort the main list in ascending order, that might work.

Comment: Did you try the Customize Group Name Field with the formula under options?  Add the following formula left({yourfield.name},5)  You would also need to replace the actual group name back onto your report if you put in a formula (available in the field explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I am not answering the exact question... 4444 is close to how I would tackle this.  I also would use a variable... I usually create 3 separate formulas.  1st titled desc and place the following formula inside:

```
shared stringvar mydesc;
mydesc := {yourdescriptionfield.name};
```

This goes into your header.

The second formula is the show, so formula descShow with the following:

```
shared stringvar mydesc;
```

Place this in your group footer

Now you need to reset the string so that the next grouping has the right description.  Formula name descReset with the following:

```
shared stringvar mydesc:= ""
```

Place this into the group header above the one you want the description (ie if you are working on GH3 place in GH2).  If it is the top group, place in the header.

Comment: okay thank you. so in this example, what, if anything, gets placed in the details section?  How do you narrow down to the description you want using those variables?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything... the header should pull the top description, which should be the .00.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Stackoverflow community win!

Comment: You actually use variables to store information when it meets certain conditions or to pass between sub and main reports. There are a few different types ie stringvar, numbervar, etc. The key differences from formulas is that you must separate each statement by ; and use := to save data into the variable. So like 4444 If Right({ItemNumber}, 2) = "00" Then myDesc := {Description}; You can also use it to count only the .00's, for instance shared numbervar 00count; if Right({ItemNumber}, 2) = "00" Then 00count:=00count+{fieldwithamount.name};

Comment: Always a good idea to reset 1 group above so it doesn't continue if you don't need it... so for the counting example shared numbervar 00count := 0;

Comment: Ah, okay, that is very handy to know.  Thank you!